# "_glFlush", referenced from:-[GLLevelMeter _drawView] in GLLevelMeter.o

Tags: ios4

whenever I am running My code it is showing an error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not linking to the right libraries. You probably want to link to the OpenGLES.framework. That's what it looks like to me.

In Xcode with your project open, select "Add to Project . . . " from the "Project" menu. Use the resulting dialog sheet to find the OpenGL project at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework